# tkinter - Weighted Canvas not Filling Empty Space

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

canvas takes up the whole screen as can be seen from the green.
canvasFrame has two rows, the second of which the scrolledtext widgets are on. The second row has also been weighted however its not filling the screeen as the green area should be yellow. How do I get the the second row to fill the empty space and get the scrolled text widgets to expand vertically.

P.S. innerFrame looks unecessary in this example but it's there because I've removed other widgets in the frame for simplicity's sake.

[image: Canvas]

code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tks

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Page, Other):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Page)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="red")
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)

        innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        innerFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frameOne = tk.Frame(innerFrame, bg="green")
        frameOne.grid(row=1, sticky="NSWE")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frameOne, bg="green")

        canvasFrame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="yellow")
        canvasFrame.pack()

        canvasFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frameOne, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=canvasFrame, anchor="nw")

        for x in range(5):
            pagename = tk.Label(canvasFrame, text = "Unit Name")
            pagename.grid(row=0, column=x, sticky="NSEW")
            text = tks.ScrolledText(canvasFrame, width=50)
            text.grid(row=1, column=x ,sticky="NSEW")

        canvasFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


class Other(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you using a canvas? if all you have are scrollable widgets in it, there's no need for the canvas. Or the other two frames for that matter. You're making the problem much more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: I need the canvas for the horizontal scrollbar, I also have widgets outside the canvas that go above and below it. The horizontal scrollbar is necessary to be able to scroll to the Scrolledtext widgets that go off of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `canvasFrame` has no reason to expand to fill the canvas. You've put widgets in it, and the frame will shrink to fit the widgets.

The most common solution is to add a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the canvas, get the height of the canvas, and use the canvas `itemconfigure` method to adjust the height of the frame to be the same as the height of the canvas.

```
class Page(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window(...)
        ...
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        # you might need to subtract a little to account for borders,
        # padding, etc.
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.frame_id, height=event.height)
```